# Stuck Clutch 1995 Alfa Romeo 916 S 2.0 l TS

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, clutch-cylinder, master-cylinder, alfa-romeo

I bought a Alfa Romeo 916 and knew I would have to do some work on it, including replacing the clutch. I bought a LuK clutch and replaced the clutch plate, pressure plate, and throwout bearing (Flywheel was fine, no grooves or pitting or obvious signs of wear). Since putting the gearbox back on and reconnecting the clutch line / hose to the slave cylinder the clutch is stuck in the disengaged position (I think. Easy to spin wheels by hand when in gear.) I have looked at the master and slave cylinders and can't see any sign of leakages, and the reseviour still has oil in it. The clutch line / hose is a little deformed as I accidentally bent it when removing the gearbox, I have heard this could be the cause of the problem, but I'm not sure.

Unfortunately the clutch kit did not come with an alignment tool and I was unable to find one (I live in Switzerland) so I had to make do using a socket extension, dowels and masking tape to make a very tight fitting tool. I think I had the clutch plate aligned properly as the gearbox went back onto the engine with no problems.

What may be the cause of this issue?

Milage: Approximately 200000 Km
Manual Transmission

Thank you very much.

Comment: If your transmission mounted correctly then there should be no worry about clutch plate alignment. If the friction disk is not aligned properly, the transmission will not mount back onto the engine. Did you check that the throwout bearing and clutch arm were installed correctly? I'd think this may be a problem area if not which may force the clutch open and not allow it to engage correctly.

Comment: Are you actually sure it is going into gear when you tested it? Did you test the transmission when you had it out of the vehicle to ensure it was functioning properly? (ie: run it through the gears ensuring the output shaft is spinning in accordance with input shaft speed). Also, if both wheels are off the ground, unless your Alfa has a locking differential, the other tire is going to spin opposite of the tire you're spinning. If you aren't watching to see what it's doing, the whole thing will spin very freely.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 No I didn’t check it when it was out. Though it was working before I took it out the first time. Tomorrow I will get someone to help me check if the other wheel spins opposite. I did notice before I put it back in though that the the left wheel output spun opposite to the left.

Answer (score 0):

One classic error is to put the clutch centre plate in the wrong way round.

One face is marked with "flywheel side" or similar.

Difficult to check though...

Comment: Yes I was aware of this when fitting it. It wasn't marked but I removed mine and immediately put the new one on with the same orientation. With the 'snout' pointing towards the transmission and the flat side towards the flywheel.